# Create a cover page when using window.print()

Tags: html, css

I have header and footer when i printing.

But on the first page, i just want that cover page to be clean. So i only can have a picture or title there.
Right now i have my header and footer also at this cover page. I don´t want that.

I have tried to use

@page:first {margin:0;}

I still have the header and footer.

Give me the easiest way to do this in CSS, and please explain why.

The Code

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page-header ">
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <p>Hello</p>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div class="page-footer">
    I'm The Footer
  </div>

  <table>

    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <!--place holder for the fixed-position header-->
          <div class="page-header-space"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <!--*** CONTENT GOES HERE ***-->
          <div class="masthead">
            <p>Hello</p>
          </div>
          <div class="page">
            <div>
              <p class="test">&nbsp; </p>

            </div>
            <div class=" col test-2">

              <p>
                Text
              </p>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="page">
            <div>
              <p class="test-3">&nbsp; </p>
              <h1 style="text-align:center">Text</h1>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top: 100px;">
              <p>Text.</p>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="page">
            <div>
              <p style="margin-top:10px;">
                <h1 class="test">Text</h1>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <p class="test-5">&nbsp; </p>
              <h2 style="text-align:left">Text</h2>
            </div>
            <div>
              <p class="test-5">&nbsp; </p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <div>
                <p class="test-5">&nbsp; </p>
              </div>
              <br />
              <div>
                <p class="test-5">&nbsp; </p>
              </div>
              <br />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="page">
            <div>
              <p style="margin-top:10px;">
                <h1 class="test">Text</h1>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <!--place holder for the fixed-position footer-->
          <div class="page-footer-space"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: maybe if you show us what you've tried.

Comment: Show your html code so that we can help you.

Comment: @CanUver and Khalid Khan now i have put my html code for the page setup.
Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 2):

You may add an element to display as first page, like this:

```
<div class="print-first-page">
    your first page content here
</div>
```

Then hide it from screen and show on printed page:

```
.print-first-page {
    display: none;
}
@media print {
    .print-first-page {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

}
```

Here is the complete example with your code:

```
<head>
    <style>
.print-first-page {
    display: none;
}
@media print {
    .print-first-page {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="print-first-page">
    your first page content here
</div>
<div class="page-header ">
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <p>Hello</p>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="page-footer">
    I'm The Footer
</div>

<table>

    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!--place holder for the fixed-position header-->
            <div class="page-header-space"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!--*** CONTENT GOES HERE ***-->
            <div class="masthead">
                <p>Hello</p>
            </div>
            <div class="page">
                <div>
                    <p class="test">&nbsp; </p>

                </div>
                <div class=" col test-2">

                    <p>
                        Text
                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="page">
                <div>
                    <p class="test-3">&nbsp; </p>
                    <h1 style="text-align:center">Text</h1>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top: 100px;">
                    <p>Text.</p>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="page">
                <div>
                    <p style="margin-top:10px;"><h1 class="test">Text</h1></p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p class="test-5">&nbsp; </p>
                    <h2 style="text-align:left">Text</h2>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p class="test-5">&nbsp; </p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <p class="test-5">&nbsp; </p>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div>
                        <p class="test-5">&nbsp; </p>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="page">
                <div>
                    <p style="margin-top:10px;"><h1 class="test">Text</h1></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!--place holder for the fixed-position footer-->
            <div class="page-footer-space"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: With this solution, every this is gone.
My problem is that, I want to get rid of the header and footer from the first page.

Comment: This worked beautiful for me.  I styled the cover page, set the display to none by default.  Then for the media print CSS, I set display to block.

Comment: @AndersDahl were you able to get rid of the header and footer from the first page?